# Visual Studio 2010 Cannot Resolve Moniker 877c

Tags: visual-studio, architecture, sequence-diagram

I created a few sequence diagrams in VS 2010 and when I try to open them in design view I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve moniker '8cc714d1-d71f-4f0f-a3b5-a34b74dfb852'

I searched the Sequence Diagram XML and could not find this GUID.  How do I resolve this error so I can open my diagram?

Answer (score 3):

It says that there are some references which layout file cannot resolve.

For this you just need to delete  `.dbml.layout`  file.

[image]

And then just double click on .dbml file.

Answer (score 0):

Just received this error in VS 2015, along with a few other very strange ones. Everything I tried, including reverting the file, had no effect. I restarted Visual Studio, did another Build, and the errors were gone.